# Unable to set JAVA_OPTS in tomcats setenv

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I set the following line in tomcats setenv.bat:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=production"
```

When I start the server, the following error is displayed:

```
The command "JAVA_OPTS" is either written wrong or could not be found.
```

What is wrong here? How can I set java options else?

Win7, Java 7

Comment: Are you using Windows, mac or linux?

Comment: windows, updated above

Comment: looks like you are using a unix style syntax in a windows style command file

Comment: try `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% "-Dspring.profiles.active=production"` or similar

Answer (score 1):

You should use the windows style

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dspring.profiles.active=production
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it works wrapping the variable in `%`, anyhow I had to remove the wrapping quotes to make it work.